# Unable to install virtual environement module onto Vscode ("[Errno 2] No such file or directory")

Tags: python, file, selenium-webdriver, virtual, environment

```
PS C:\Users\fookl\OneDrive\Desktop\shopee_scraping> py pip venv .venv
C:\Users\fookl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\fookl\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\shopee_scraping\\pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I want to install selenium on my Vscode however, the tutorial recommended me to setup virtual environment. As I was setting up the venv, the error keeps coming up for no such file or directory so I don't know how to fix it

Even if I want to install selenium onto the file, shopee_scraping, it shows up for the same error and I don't know how to fix this issue

Comment: The first argument to `py` should be an actual python script, such as `myscript.py`.  But `pip` is not.  Why are you using `pip` as the first argument here?

Answer (score 0):

To create a virtual environment

```
python -m venv .your_virtual_env_name
```

Comment: When I typed (py pip install virtualenv), the same error came up. [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Chris. Edit the answer

Comment: @SirojWongpitakroj, have you tried copy and pasting the command? Stop adding "py" in your commands

Comment: Oh I got it, Thanks a lot. I normally used "py" at the start of every command because when i want to install any python module I would have to type "py pip -m install module"